# Getting ImportError: No module named 'sklearn' when installing auto-sklearn

Tags: python

Why do I get `ImportError: No module named 'sklearn'` when installing `auto-sklearn` via pip?

```
$ virtualenv -p python3 automl
$ cd automl/
$ source bin/activate
$ pip install auto-sklearn
Collecting auto-sklearn
  Downloading auto-sklearn-0.1.1.tar.gz (5.9MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 5.9MB 265kB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-whq6xjt6/auto-sklearn/setup.py", line 2, in     <module>
        import autosklearn
      File "/tmp/pip-build-whq6xjt6/auto-sklearn/autosklearn/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
        from autosklearn.util import dependencies
      File "/tmp/pip-build-whq6xjt6/auto-sklearn/autosklearn/util/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
        from .common import *
      File "/tmp/pip-build-whq6xjt6/auto-sklearn/autosklearn/util/common.py", line 4, in <module>
        from sklearn.externals import six
    ImportError: No module named 'sklearn'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-whq6xjt6/auto-sklearn/
```

There seems to be missing dependencies in the pip distribution. But why is the automatic installation of dependencies not working? I can install auto-sklearn in this way:

```
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/automl/auto-sklearn/master/requirements.txt
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
$ pip install numpy six Cython      # something goes wrong here too!?
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
$ pip install auto-sklearn
```

I have looked at the tar.gz tar file at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/auto-sklearn/0.1.1 and the `install_requires` in `setup.py` seems ok to me. Does the `MANIFEST.in` needs a `requirements.txt` line?

I put up an issue on GitHub for this at https://github.com/automl/auto-sklearn/issues/206 but that has been closed. What is the reason for that manual installation is necessary?

Comment: pip install sklearn?

Comment: apt-get install python-sklearn?

Comment: As I wrote I can get non-automated installation of dependencies to work. My question concerned why it does not install automatically. Is it a bug or feature in auto-sklearn, a bug on my system or a "bug" in my understanding of how dependency installation should work with pip?

Comment: To clarify: "scikit-learn==0.17.1" is both mentioned in `setup.py` and `requirements.txt`. It gets installed with `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: The problem is a the top of the `setup.py` file where the package is imported before it is installed https://github.com/automl/auto-sklearn/blob/master/setup.py#L2