# Auto-sklearn installation error

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pip

I'm trying to install auto-sklearn using `pip install auto-sklearn`, but it raises the error:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python3.5 -u -c "
    import setuptools, tokenize;
    __file__='/tmp/pip-build-tl8y2tfg/psutil/setup.py';
    f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);
    code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');
    f.close();
    exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))
"install 
    --record /tmp/pip-7t8rbku0-record/install-record.txt 
    --single-version-externally-managed --compile" 
failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-tl8y2tfg/psutil/
```

There is nothing starting with "pip-" in my `/tmp/` directory.

I made all steps exactly as in [manual](http://automl.github.io/auto-sklearn/stable/installation.html), but still have this error.

I also tried to use commands from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244479/getting-importerror-no-module-named-sklearn-when-installing-auto-sklearn), but got the same error in both cases.

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04.2.

How can I install auto-sklearn?

Comment: http://automl.github.io/auto-sklearn/stable/installation.html

Comment: I made all steps from here.

Comment: Can you add your OS to the question?

Comment: I added this to the question.

Comment: can you run your command with -v or --verbose or something like that to see more datails ?

Answer (score 2):

`auto-sklearn` installation requires python 3.5 or higher. In addition, it also has dependencies on the packages mentioned here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/automl/auto-sklearn/master/requirements.txt

As per the error, you seem to have an issue at `psutil` installation.

A better approach is to have a python 3.5+ environment. And then using `pip install auto-sklearn`.

- Check which version/path are you using - `which python`, `which pip`
- Install python 3.5 or higher, if you don't have it already: [steps to follow](https://tecadmin.net/install-python-3-5-on-ubuntu/)
- Once you have the correct version of python installed, set up a virtual environment of the python3.5. [Follow](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtualenv/) the code to setup a virtual environment:

`python3 -m pip install --user virtualenv`

`source env/bin/activate`

- Finally call `pip install auto-sklearn`

**Update:**

- In case you are using anaconda, following command will start your virtual env:

  `conda update conda` #Update your current version of conda

  `conda create --name py35 python=3.5` #creat e a virtual env for python 3.5

  `source activate py35` #activate the environment

Post your query here, again in case you are not sure of the steps.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming to this question, I encountered this issue trying to install on OSX. The author may have left off some of her stack trace. Namely:

```
    Installing collected packages: pyrfr
  Running setup.py install for pyrfr ... error
    Complete output from command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/g5/vdl1tlwd333d5vzfw4qfc86c0000gp/T/pip-install-zy5yrmfh/pyrfr/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/g5/vdl1tlwd333d5vzfw4qfc86c0000gp/T/pip-record-iuj3muyd/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=:
    running install
    running build_ext
    building 'pyrfr._regression' extension
    swigging pyrfr/regression.i to pyrfr/regression_wrap.cpp
    swig -python -c++ -modern -features nondynamic -I./include -o pyrfr/regression_wrap.cpp pyrfr/regression.i
    unable to execute 'swig': No such file or directory
    error: command 'swig' failed with exit status 1
```

Your installation errors are likely caused by not having swig installed.

Swig is a C / C ++ code generator, an interface for python to use C libraries.

You can install it by following the instructions at their project website here:
http://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/SWIGDocumentation.pdf

Basically, download the most recent tarball archive from the website. Extract it. cd to the extracted folder and run:

```
./configure
make
make install
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/automl/auto-sklearn/master/requirements.txt | xargs -n 1 -L 1 pip3 install
```

And you should be good to run auto-sklearn.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sudo` to write to system libraries often leads to trouble, as important variables like PATH will be different when running under different ids. Instead, follow the advice in the [manual](http://automl.github.io/auto-sklearn/stable/installation.html), and install within a virtualenv, running as an ordinary user.

Answer (score 0):

This is for completeness - please upvote Wolf's answer!

Just to build on Wolf Rendall's excellent answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57964642/1021819):

You do indeed need swig - but under macOS one can install it easly via homebrew, i.e.

```
brew install swig
```

followed by

```
pip install auto-sklearn
```

(Wolf is right that there's some missing stacktrace.)

Then you should be off to the races. Thanks Wolf!